# not able to install mysql on ubuntu 11

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to install mysql in my Ubuntu 11.10. I use sudo apt-get install mysql-server in the terminal to install.

It gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.1
 mysql-server
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try removing apparmor package:

```
sudo apt-get remove apparmor
```

and then re-attempt the installation with mysql-common package:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mysql-server
```

Comment: @BluewsRockAddict: not sure why it works but it does :) can u explain why? And also what is 'apparmor'? do i have to re-install it?

Comment: Most likely there was a dependency conflict and removing apparmor just cleared things up. AppArmor is a kernel module, you don't need to re-install it as it was installed during mysql installation.

Answer (score 4):

Given the following, it will definitely work. I racked my brain for hours and this helped finally:

1. `dpkg --remove mysql-server-5.5`

   or just

   `dpkg --remove mysql-server`
2. `sudo apt-get purge -f mysql-server mysql-common`
3. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error "

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

I did this
http://hunt4.biz/wordpress/?p=25

$ mysqld

After Reboot open a shell and enter the following:

```
1. ~$ sudo mysqld &
2. ~$ ps -aux | grep mysqld
```

Look for something like this:

```
mysql    27035  0.0  0.7 180584 27412 ?        Ssl  08:41   0:05 /usr/sbin/mysqld
3. ~$ sudo kill -9  27035
4. ~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start or sudo service mysql start
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get remove apparmor
```

solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete (as superuser) my /var/lib/mysql folder.  Before I did that, I tried the above solutions repeatedly (different permutations thereof) unsuccessfully. FYI.