# Mysql installation ubuntu server: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

I wanted to configure remote access to my database. I could not configurate this and I decided to reinstall ssh and mysql. After reinstallation i have this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

When I wanted to reinstall mysql I get this error:

> AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in
>   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open
>   'abstractions/mysql'

Comment: Possibly duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972611/not-able-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-11#answer-9972681

Comment: Warning to anybody cutting and pasting from the answer above. `find / -name 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;` is a remarkably dangerous command run.

Answer (score -1):

This error occur when uninstall mysql5.7 and install mysql8 in virtual machine ubuntu18.10.
Message:
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 7: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'

Then I create file /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql but other error occur.
Message:
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_END_OF_RULE, expecting TOK_MODE

It seems like we cannot uninstall the previous mysql use those command below.

```
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql 
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld 
find / -name 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I removed this bad VM and run the copy mysql5.7 VM. 
Uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Reinstall:

```
wget –c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This error do not occur. Or maybe u need to restore files

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
```